# refresh the contents of jquery data table on drop down change

Tags: jquery

I am trying get json results on to jquery data table. I have got results but when ever i change drop down values the data table won't get refreshed. I have tried with

```
fnClearTable();

clear();

fnDestroy();
```

but it dint work.

**DataTable**

```
function table(obj) {

    if (obj != null && obj.length > 0) {
        // var dynamicColumns = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each(obj[0], function (key, val) {
            var objectt = { sTitle: key };

            dynamicColumns[i] = objectt;
            i++;
        });

        var i = 0;
        $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
            var rowData = [];
            var j = 0;
            $.each(obj[i], function (key, val) {
                rowData[j] = val;
                j++;
            });
            rowDataSet[i] = rowData;

            i++;
        });


     $('#tbDetails').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "bDestroy": true,              
            "bretrieve": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sScrollY": "200px",
            "bInfo": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            "aaData": rowDataSet,
            "aoColumns": dynamicColumns  //These are dynamically created columns present in JSON object.

        });

        $("#PlotResults").dialog('open');
    }
}
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: @nandini can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
// Dropdown on change event
$('#myDropdown').on('change', function(){

    var myTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable();  // get the table ID

    // If you want totally refresh the datatable use this 
    myTable.ajax.reload();

    // If you want to refresh but keep the paging you can you this
    myTable.ajax.reload( null, false );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. it works fine now. i haven't clear the rowDataSet before.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if the solution solved your problem ?